# A link not allowing my Jquery code to execute

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with my jquery not working with a link wrapped in a  class

HTML:

```
<span class="back_btn">
    <a href=""><img src="images/back.png" id="img_resize" /></a>
</span>
```

Jquery:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
             $(".back_btn").click(function(){
                 $("#login_form").delay("fast").fadeOut(500);
                 $("#main_form").delay("slow").fadeIn(2000);

     });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hook the `click` event for that `anchor` tag and prevent its default behavior(redirecting to other link) by using `e.preventDefault()`.

Try,

```
$(".back_btn a").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#login_form").delay("fast").fadeOut(500);
 $("#main_form").delay("slow").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: You should also explain behavior of change. `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: sure, I'll have to wait 15 mins though because of new account :)